# How to show the sequence $\{f(n)\}$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \infty$. Suppose $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + f(x)^2}$. I need to show $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ exists.

I first considered $\{f(n)\}$ and tried to show its bounded in order to show $f$ is bounded. I used the MVT to arrive at $f(n + 1) - f(n) \le \frac{1}{n^2}$, but from here, I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I'm using baby Rudin and I haven't covered integration yet. I was instructed to use only the continuity and differentiation sections

Answer (score 2):

Compare your $f$ with the solution of $g'(x)=1/x^2$, starting at $g(1)=1$.  Since $f(x)^2\ge0$ you have $f'(x)\le g'(x)$ for $x\ge1$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By induction
$$f(n) \leq f(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Since the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$ is convergent to some $C$  (which is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but this is irrelevant) you get 
$$f(n) \leq f(1)+C$$

Also, since $f'(x) > 0$ your function is non-decreasing and hence 
$$f(1) \leq f(n) \leq f(1)+C$$

Now, use the fact that $f$ is increasing and that each $x \in [1, \infty)$ can be put between two integers.

Comment: Why is induction required here? It seems to follow without it with the step I have above. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @user439126 Yes, it follows by adding $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k+1)-f(k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^2}$$ and the fact that the LHS is telescopic. But that's basically induction.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{f(k+1)-f(k)}=f(n)-f(1)\leq {\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{n^2}}}\leq 2.$ Now $(f(n)$ is an increasing bounded sequence, it converges.

Comment: Does this require induction?

Comment: Induction not required.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to prove formally that the telescopic sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{f(k+1)-f(k)}=f(n)-f(1)$$, that's induction,;)

Comment: Not necessary, one can change variable.